# How to select the validation loss value in this model to be compared with other models?

Tags: lstm, loss-function, validation, mse

I'm training an LSTM model. I'm confusing about the validation loss of the model. Which value better represents the validation loss of the model? Is it the last value I obtain in the floowing loop, or I should calculate the mean of all the history values?

This is my model

```
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        lstm.train()
        outputs = lstm.forward(X_train) # forward pass
        optimiser.zero_grad() # calculate the gradient, manually setting to 0
        # obtain the loss function
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, y_train)
        loss.backward() # calculates the loss of the loss function
        optimiser.step() # improve from loss, i.e backprop
        train_loss_history.append(loss.item())
        # test loss
        lstm.eval()
        test_preds = lstm(X_test)
        MSEtest_loss = loss_fn(test_preds, y_test)
        val_loss_history.append(MSEtest_loss.item())
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch: %d, train loss: %1.5f, val MSE loss: %1.5f " % (epoch, 
                                                                      loss.item(), 
                                                                      MSEtest_loss.item(),
                                                                      ))
```

Now, is the last value of  `MSEtest_loss.item()` represents the validation loss of the model? or Should I calculate the `val_loss_history`to represent the validation loss of the model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are recording the validation loss for each epoch in the val_loss_history list. This list contains all the validation loss values throughout the training process. To evaluate the validation loss of your model, you can consider both the last value of MSEtest_loss.item() and the val_loss_history.

The last value of MSEtest_loss.item() represents the validation loss of the model at the last epoch of training. It gives you the validation loss for that specific epoch.

On the other hand, the val_loss_history contains the validation loss values for each epoch throughout the training process. By examining the entire history of validation loss values, you can get insights into how the validation loss has changed over time and assess the overall performance of your model during training.

To summarize, you can use the last value of MSEtest_loss.item() as an indicator of the model's performance at the final epoch, and you can analyze the val_loss_history to understand the trend and fluctuations in the validation loss during training.

Comment: Thank you @Anandaprabhu